# Why my cronjob setup by Ansible is not running?

Tags: cron, vagrant, ansible

I've setup a cron job by Ansible but when I use `crontab -l` it's said that my cron is empty.

Here's my script to set it up.

```
  - name: Setup cron to run backup.sh every midnight
    cron: 
      name="Backup S3 to GS" 
      minute="0"
      hour="0"
      job="sh ~/backup.sh"
      cron_file=backup_s3
      user=vagrant
```

But when I go inside the vagrant machine and ls `/etc/cron.d/` I can see that `backup_s3` file is there. But when I use command `crontab -l` it's said it's empty.

This is the content of `backup_s3`

```
#Ansible: Backup S3 to GS
0 0 * * * vagrant sh ~/backup.sh
```

I know that it's not running because I don't get any email saying that the backup is done and when I run the script manually it's working fine.

Comment: Crontab is per user, so you might see a different user's crontab when using crontab -l, namely the file of the user you are logged in with.

Comment: I logged on as `vagrant`. However, is there anyway I can check if my cron is actually running correctly.

Comment: I allways let the cronjob simple create a directory in a place the actual script needs to work. Like this I know that a) cron is working and b) the permissions are setup correctly. I can't tell from here what the problem with your cronjob is, but permissions are a very common pitfall. You also could try to use the full path to sh in your cron line

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay. There are several layers of confusion here.

First, the crontab you see when you edit (`crontab -e`) or view (`crontab -l`) is a *user* cron. This sits in a magic spool directory/file. You can't edit it directly (approximately speaking), and it's not a good place to put any serious crons.

Since you are using `cron_file=`, Ansible is doing the appropriate thing by placing an entry in `/etc/cron.d/`. That means individual files can be placed there, which is much more sane than trying to edit a document. ([look at all the people struggling with `lineinfile` here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bansible%5D+lineinfile))

This is why it isn't showing up in `crontab -l`, and it's a good thing.

As far as output from cron is concerned, does email even work for your Vagrant system? It likely doesn't. There are good ways around this. First, look at `/var/log/cron`. If you don't have one, look for `CRON` entries in `/var/log/syslog`. They may indicate if there are problems.

Next, crons typically don't have good access to a user shell. That means you should avoid `~`. Further, if your permissions are wrong on `backup.sh`, it may not get executed. Finally, you can pipe output so you can see it. Here's what I'd recommend doing with your cron entry:

```
job="/bin/sh /home/vagrant/backup.sh >> /home/vagrant/backup.log"
```

You can also modify the `minute`/`hour` so it runs more frequently- so you don't have to wait overnight to see what is happening.

Once you've done that, you have plenty of places to look for information. There are two places in `/var/log`, there's a new `backup.log` which will give you information (if it exists, the cron has been run; if there is data in it, you should be able to figure out any problems).

### TLDR

Change the `job` line. Look for execution in `/var/log` and `/home/vagrant/backup.log`.

Comment: Using `name=` does not place the file in `/etc/cron.d/`,  using `cron_file=` will cause it to look there.  http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/cron_module.html

Comment: fixed. Note that in the future you can edit it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @tedder42, I'm new to using ansible with cron, and to using cron seriously so don't feel confident yet.  I might come back to make some edits :)  For example, after running my ansible cron task I can see the entries in `crontab -l` when I'm as the user (`vagrant` in the OPs case).  I think my problem was due to the file I copied into the job location not being executable and also from using `job=/some/script.sh` without the `job=sh ...` part or `#!/bin/sh` at the start of the .sh file.